# Function call to object created by directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following situation:

Having my main view containing header, footer and ng-view to load the view according to the controller  (controller chosen based on route).

```
<header></header>
<div ng-view="" class="fill"></div>
<footer>
  <span ng-click="nextSlide(swiper)">Next Slide</span>
</footer>
```

In the controller i have a view with a directive creating a slider and returning the slider object:

```
    angular.module('App').directive('npSwiper', [
  '$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
          // This code will run after template has been loaded
          // and transformed by directives
          $timeout(function() {
            // and properly rendered by the browser
            $timeout(function() {
              $timeout(function() {
                var params = {
                  slideElement: 'article',
                  mode: 'horizontal',
                  calculateHeight: true,
                  paginationClickable: true,
                  pagination: '.pagination',
                  resizeReInit: true
                };
                if (attrs.npSwiper === 'gallery') {
                  params.slidesPerView = 1;
                  params.createPagination = false;
                  params.loop = true;
                }
                scope.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', params);
                console.log('directive', scope.swiper);

                new Swiper('.swiper-container-instagram', {
                  slideElement: 'article',
                  mode: 'horizontal',
                  calculateHeight: false,
                  paginationClickable: true,
                  pagination: '.pagination-instagram',
                  resizeReInit: true
                });

              });
            });
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

I can make a function

```
$scope.nextSlide = function(slider) {
  slider.swipeNext();
}
```

assigned to ng-click to a span for example in the same view that is being loaded from the controller, but when I want to assign it to the footer (outside the slider view) it gives no result.

Also calling the swiper from the controller by simply:

```
$scope.swiper
```

gives undefined. Any ideas how to reach it?

Comment: Using $timeout in such a way seems wrong. You declared your directive as attribute. Mention it as such: <span swipe>blabla</span>

Comment: @roland Sorry Im just learning angular and this is the directive that I've found.  It is included as `<div data-np-swiper="" class="">content here</div>`